blacklistd on freebsd not consistently blocking on ssh timeout
Roughly every minute, I'm getting the following in my log:
sshd[####]: fatal: Timeout before authentication for 118.26.194.190
There are many hundreds, this has been happening for hours.
# grep 118.26.194.190 /var/log/console.log | wc
     238    4284   32368
So I'm looking at 'blacklistd' to see why it's not working.
# blacklistctl dump -a | grep 118.26.194.190
118.26.194.190/32:22   OK      3/3     2024/04/01 16:09:20
# ipfw table port22 list
118.26.194.190/32 0
In the time I've been typing this, it finally figured it out. Just a few minutes ago this IP was NOT in the 'ipfw' output, and the blacklistctl line showed "2/3".  Regardless, it obviously wasn't working as there should only be 3 attempts before 'ipfw' blocking occurs, clearly that didn't happen.  (There are a few other entries in table 'port22', and many other entries in 'port25' and 'port587' so things are working.)  When I do a 'grep' for same IP address in the log, all the entries are the same timeout as above.
Thoughts anyone?

you will not get an answer here, SO is about programming, yours is about OS admin. See unix at stackexchange

Thanks for the heads-up -- moved discussion to stackexchange.  Should I delete this one?
